# sub query in select clause vs Apply operator performance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm testing performance of related sub query in a select clause vs outer apply. Why should correlated sub query in select clause perform better than OUTER APPLY

--Correlated sub query in select---

```
SELECT
    (SELECT TOP 1 
         L.LineNum
     FROM RDR1 L
     WHERE T1.Docentry = L.DocEntry
     ORDER BY L.Linenum DESC) as LineNum,
   T1.Docentry, T1.Docdate, T1.CardCode, *
FROM 
   ORDR T1

--36 sec--
```

--outer apply --

```
SELECT
   L.LineNum,T1.Docentry,T1.Docdate,T1.CardCode,*
FROM 
   ORDR T1
OUTER APPLY
   (SELECT TOP 1 
        T2.LineNum
    FROM RDR1 T2
    WHERE T1.Docentry = T2.DocEntry
    ORDER BY T2.Linenum DESC) as L
--42sec--
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at at query plan

```
Select max(T2.LineNum), T1.Docentry, T1.Docdate, T1.CardCode
  FROM ORDR T1
  join RDR1 t2 
    on T1.Docentry = T2.DocEntry 
 group by T1.Docentry, T1.Docdate, T1.CardCode
```

Comment: Thanks. We can use this code but what I'm after is GENERALLY should apply be faster than a related sub query?

Comment: Did you look at the query plans?  I am suggesting you should use this GENERALLY over either of those.  In practice you need to test with your query and your data.